# Kendo UI add row to grouping

Tags: kendo-ui

Is it possible to add a new row to a grid grouping? I have a custom button that needs to do this?

I have checked the documentation here: http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#addrow, but I am unsure how to set a parameter there; let's say;  `grid.addRow(TASK_ID=1)`, or something like that. How is this possible?

Also, how do you define an array in the model schema?

Json array object within another, for something like this:

```
{
   feature_ID: 1,
   TASKS:{
        TASK_ID:
        TASK_NAME
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grid.one("edit", function (e) {
    e.model.set("ID", 20);
});
grid.addRow();
```

Comment: Is there a way to add a row so that it's not editable initially?